# Println only two value from JSON

Tags: java, json, jersey-client

I'm using Jersey Client to read json information about countries.

```
Client client = Client.create();
String getUrl = "http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/norway";

WebResource webResource = client.resource(getUrl);
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
if(response.getStatus()!=200){
    throw new RuntimeException("HTTP Error: "+ response.getStatus());
}

String result = response.getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println("Response from the Server: ");
System.out.println(result);
```

But my code return all information, the same like on web page:

```
[{"name":"Norway","capital":"Oslo","altSpellings":["NO","Norge","Noreg","Kingdom of Norway","Kongeriket Norge","Kongeriket Noreg"],"relevance":"1.5","region":"Europe","subregion":"Northern Europe","translations":{"de":"Norwegen","es":"Noruega","fr":"Norvège","ja":"ノルウェー","it":"Norvegia"},"population":5156450,"latlng":[62.0,10.0],"demonym":"Norwegian","area":323802.0,"gini":25.8,"timezones":["UTC+01:00"],"borders":["FIN","SWE","RUS"],"nativeName":"Norge","callingCodes":["47"],"topLevelDomain":[".no"],"alpha2Code":"NO","alpha3Code":"NOR","currencies":["NOK"],"languages":["no","nb","nn"]}]
```

I wanted to ask if exists any way to println only "name" and "capital".

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the response into a java object and than you can use only those parameters which are really useful.

see this tutorial: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/bind/jaxb-json-example/

it has an example of converting from java to json and json to java as well